# javascript function on HtmlDataTable (richfaces) render

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces, render

I'm using HtmlDataTable from richfaces and I need to call a javascript function everytime the grid is rendered (eg: pagination, sort by column, etc). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can try 
a4j:support onbeforedomupdate="..." 
inside your HtmlDataTable tag.